# Accessing the value of function from if statement

Tags: python, syntax

Is it possible to shorten the syntax and access the value of the function from the if statement without explicitly declaring returning value? For example, write this way:

```
if some_func():
    print('Somehow got the value of some_func()')
```

instead of:

```
x = some_func()
if x:
    print(x)
```

Comment: you have answered your own question

Comment: yes, you can use it, its totally valid

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't and it would just be moving the problem around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
def optional(x):
    if x:
        yield x

for x in optional(some_func()):
    print(x)
```

But it doesn't actually make your code better because the presence of a loop is misleading. Stick to what you've got. Shorter code isn't always better.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't worth the candle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

It's possible to do so.

**eg.**

```
 def isEven(no):
     return not( no % 2)

 iN = 2
 if isEven(iN):
     print str(iN) + " is even"
  else:
     print str(iN) + " is odd"
```

when above if statement is evaluated, it'll look for the truth value of isEven(). In python, the following values have truth values false :- [], {}, empty set, 0, False, None(May be I may be missing few more). Otherwise, the truth value of other values is true.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The value returned from the function is used for `if` evaluation:

```
>>> def f():
...     return 1
... 
>>> if f()==1:
...    print('hey')
... 
hey
```